# How many different sets of tickets are there?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A train going from $A$ to $B$ stops at $6$ intermediate stations.  $6$ persons enter the train during the journey with $6$ different tickets of the same class. How many different sets of tickets are there?

I have approached this question like the total possible no of tickets is $6+5+4+3+2+1=21$.  The answer says $\binom{21}{6}$. All the $6$ sets of tickets may not form a valid combination that can be held by a person right? I mean the set can contain all tickets from $S_1$ to $B$ and so on. Hence, I think that's not the correct answer.

Comment: There's a concept called "punctuation" that you *really* need to study first.

Comment: @PaulSinclair can u drop a hint

Comment: "6 persons enter the train during the journey with 6 different tickets of the same class. How many different sets of tickets are there?" I have an impression that the sentence about passengers has no relation to the question. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The stations are-

```
       A..S1..S2..S3..S4..S5..S6..B
```

Anyone at S1 can buy ticket for S2 or S3.....or B i.e. 6 possible tickets. Similarly 5 for S2 and so on.

So total possible tickets are 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 21
(As you have already mentioned)

Therefore there are 21 types of tickets or 21 ways to board and leave the train for a passenger.

Now imagine all 21 tickets in front of you, when we 'choose' 6 tickets out of them, one by one ,we are not repeating the tickets. Note that the 6 passengers must have 6 different tickets.

Therefore it is a valid set and indeed the answer is correct = $\binom{21}{6}$

Comment: what I am telling is not about repeating out of 21 tickets if we choose 6 it will contain a set of 6 tickets all from S1 to S2, S1 to S3 and so on till B so with those tickets how will  other passengers travel and hence if we choose 6 out of 21 we get some invalid combinations right ?

Comment: Each passenger can get in and out of the train at the specified station in the ticket, that is independent of other passengers. Does that clarify your doubt ? If not, can you give an example of an invalid combination?

Comment: (What if all of them board in A) , (3 of them board in A and 2 of  them board in S2 and the last board in S5 and buy tickets to different destinations). Your choose formula does not allow people to buy the same ticket by all six. Does it?